# Make usable URLs during request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing an `ajax` request through `jQuery` and for example, my URL is `http://test.com/query.php?hello=foo bar`

However, the request only takes `http://test.com/query.php?hello=foo`. How do I make it so it takes even spaces? And special character entities like `&`, `-`, `!`, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make it so it takes even spaces?

By properly [url encoding](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) the space:

```
http://test.com/query.php?hello=foo+bar
```

or:

```
http://test.com/query.php?hello=foo%20bar
```

> And special character entities like &, -, !, etc.

It's the same. Make sure you url encode them properly:

- `&` => `%26`
- `-` => `-` (doesn't need to be encoded)
- `!` => `!` (doesn't need to be encoded)

In order to properly do this in javascript you could use the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function.

Or if you use jQuery you could also take a look at the [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) method.

Finally if you are sending an AJAX request using jQuery you could do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'query.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { hello: 'foo bar' },
    success: function(result) {
        ...
    }
});
```

and jQuery will take care of properly url encoding the query string parameter passed in the `data` hash.

Answer (score 0):

you can do an `encodeURI(URI)`
visit this link for more info
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI